# Rotacionar Canvas no Delphi

Tags: delphi, canvas

Eu preciso rotacionar um objeto dentro de um *canvas* no Delphi.

Exemplo rotacionar em 90 graus. Texto eu consigo é fácil, mas tenho que poder fazer para qualquer tipo objeto desenhado.

Como para uma imagem desenhada no *canvas* ou uma figura geométrica desenhada pelo *canvas*.

Exemplo:

```
Image1.canvas.font.orientation := 900; //equivale rotacionar em 90 gráus.
```

Só que eu queria para qualquer objeto desenhado no canvas, não apenas textos. Só consigo com texto conforme exemplo acima.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz uma vez da seguinte maneira, eu adiciona um texto nele e rotacionava a imagem.

```
  procedure TForm2.ConvTextOut(CV: TCanvas; const sText: String; x, y,
      angle: integer);
    var
      LogFont: TLogFont;
      SaveFont: TFont;
    begin
      SaveFont := TFont.Create;
      SaveFont.Assign(CV.Font);
      GetObject(SaveFont.Handle, sizeof(TLogFont), @LogFont);
      with LogFont do
      begin
        lfEscapement := angle *10;
        lfPitchAndFamily := FIXED_PITCH or FF_DONTCARE;
      end;
      CV.Font.Handle := CreateFontIndirect(LogFont);
      SetBkMode(CV.Handle, TRANSPARENT);
      CV.TextOut(x, y, sText);
      CV.Font.Assign(SaveFont);
      SaveFont.Free;
    end;

    ConvTextOut(Origem.Canvas, label1.caption, 0, 0, 0);
      Resultado.Width := Origem.Height;
      Resultado.Height := Origem.Width;
      Resultado.Update;
      for k := 0 to Origem.Width do
        for Y := 0 to Origem.Height do
          Resultado.Canvas.Pixels[Origem.Height-Y, k] := Origem.Canvas.Pixels[k,Y];
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara, uma forma que achei no google é bit a bit. Não sabia que tinha que ser assim.

```
procedure Rotate90(Source: TGraphic; Target: TJpegImage);
var
    SourceBmp, TargetBmp: TBitmap;
    r, c: Integer;
    x, y: Integer;
begin
    SourceBmp := TBitmap.Create;
    SourceBmp.Assign(Source);
    TargetBmp := TBitmap.Create;
    TargetBmp.Width := SourceBmp.Height;
    TargetBmp.Height := SourceBmp.Width;

    for r := 0 to SourceBmp.Height - 1 do
    begin
        for c := 0 to SourceBmp.Width - 1 do
        begin
            //x := (SourceBmp.Height-1) - r; // -90
            //y := c; //-90
            x := r; //90
            y := (SourceBmp.Width-1) - c; //90
            // look into Bitmap.ScanLine for faster pixel access
            TargetBmp.Canvas.Pixels[x, y] := SourceBmp.Canvas.Pixels[c, r];
        end;
    end;

    Target.Assign(TargetBmp);
    SourceBmp.Free;
    TargetBmp.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    Jpeg: TJPEGImage;
begin
    Jpeg := TJPEGImage.Create;
    Rotate90(Image1.Picture.Graphic, Jpeg);
    Image1.Picture.Assign(Jpeg);
    Jpeg.Free;
end;
```

Não testei mas parece correto.

Fonte: http://www.delphigroups.info/2/12/317243.html

Answer (score -1):

Sei que já tem Anos essa Pergunta, mas eu acabei de passar um bom tempo Pesquisando e Todas as Respostas Demoravam 8 Segundos para Girar em 90 Graus. Tempo demais, Então Encontrei essa Resposta, que é instantânea e Fiz Algumas Melhorias. Espero que ajude alguém:

```
function rotacionarImagem(Bitmap: TBitmap; const Angulo: Extended): TBitmap;
type
  PRGBQuadArray = ^TRGBQuadArray;
  TRGBQuadArray = array[0..0] of TRGBQuad;
var
  bgRGB: TRGBQuad;
  BitmapInfo: TBitmapInfo;
  CosTheta: Extended;
  DC: HDC;
  dstBMP: HBITMAP;
  dstHeight: Integer;
  dstRGB: PRGBQuad;
  dstRGBs: PRGBQuadArray;
  dstWidth: Integer;
  iCosTheta: Integer;
  iSinTheta: Integer;
  NormalAngle: Extended;
  SinTheta: Extended;
  srcBMP: HBITMAP;
  srcHeight: Integer;
  srcRGBs: PRGBQuadArray;
  srcWidth: Integer;
  xDst: Integer;
  xODst: Integer;
  xOSrc: Integer;
  xPrime: Integer;
  xSrc: Integer;
  yDst: Integer;
  yODst: Integer;
  yOSrc: Integer;
  yPrime: Integer;
  yPrimeCosTheta: Integer;
  yPrimeSinTheta: Integer;
  ySrc: Integer;
  bgColor: TColor;
begin
  bgColor := Bitmap.TransparentColor and not $02000000;
  // Convertendo o background da imagem em formato RGB:
  bgColor := ColorToRGB(bgColor);
  with bgRGB do
  begin
    rgbRed := Byte(bgColor);
    rgbGreen := Byte(bgColor shr 8);
    rgbBlue := Byte(bgColor shr 16);
    rgbReserved := Byte(bgColor shr 24);
  end;

  // Calculando o Sen e Cos do ângulo de rotação:
  NormalAngle := Frac(Angulo / 360.0) * 360.0;
  SinCos(Pi * -NormalAngle / 180, SinTheta, CosTheta);
  iSinTheta := Trunc(SinTheta * (1 shl 16));
  iCosTheta := Trunc(CosTheta * (1 shl 16));

  // Ajustando o bitmap de origem:
  srcBMP := Bitmap.Handle;
  srcWidth := Bitmap.Width;
  srcHeight := Bitmap.Height;
  xOSrc := srcWidth shr 1;
  yOSrc := srcHeight shr 1;

  // Preparando a imagem de destino:
  dstWidth := SmallInt((srcWidth * Abs(iCosTheta) +
    srcHeight * Abs(iSinTheta)) shr 16);
  dstHeight := SmallInt((srcWidth * Abs(iSinTheta) +
    srcHeight * Abs(iCosTheta)) shr 16);
  xODst := dstWidth shr 1;
  if not Odd(dstWidth) and
    ((NormalAngle = 0.0) or (NormalAngle = -90.0)) then
    Dec(xODst);
  yODst := dstHeight shr 1;
  if not Odd(dstHeight) and
    ((NormalAngle = 0.0) or (NormalAngle = +90.0)) then
    Dec(yODst);

  // Inicializa o header do bitmap:
  FillChar(BitmapInfo, SizeOf(BitmapInfo), 0);
  with BitmapInfo.bmiHeader do
  begin
    biSize := SizeOf(BitmapInfo.bmiHeader);
    biCompression := BI_RGB;
    biBitCount := 32;
    biPlanes := 1;
  end;

  // Lendo bits RGB do bitmap de origem e destino:
  DC := CreateCompatibleDC(0);
  try
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth := srcWidth;
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight := srcHeight;
    GetMem(srcRGBs, srcWidth * srcHeight * SizeOf(TRGBQuad));
    GdiFlush;
    GetDIBits(DC, srcBMP, 0, srcHeight, srcRGBS, BitmapInfo,
      DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth := dstWidth;
    BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight := dstHeight;
    dstBMP := CreateDIBSection(DC, BitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS,
      Pointer(dstRGBs), 0, 0);
  finally
    DeleteDC(DC);
  end;

  // Rotacionando:
  dstRGB := @dstRGBs[(dstWidth * dstHeight) - 1];
  yPrime := yODst;
  for yDst := dstHeight - 1 downto 0 do
  begin
    yPrimeSinTheta := yPrime * iSinTheta;
    yPrimeCosTheta := yPrime * iCosTheta;
    xPrime := xODst;
    for xDst := dstWidth - 1 downto 0 do
    begin
      xSrc := SmallInt((xPrime * iCosTheta - yPrimeSinTheta)
        shr 16) + xOSrc;
      ySrc := SmallInt((xPrime * iSinTheta + yPrimeCosTheta)
        shr 16) + yOSrc;
      if (DWORD(ySrc) < DWORD(srcHeight)) and
        (DWORD(xSrc) < DWORD(srcWidth)) then
        dstRGB^ := srcRGBs[ySrc * srcWidth + xSrc]
      else
        dstRGB^ := bgRGB;
      Dec(dstRGB);
      Dec(xPrime);
    end;
    Dec(yPrime);
  end;
  FreeMem(srcRGBs);

  // Resultado:
  Result := TBitmap.Create;
  Result.Handle := dstBMP;
end;
```